# What votes/edits do count towards badges?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, voting

There are badges which you earn when you have voted/edited `x` number of times in a day or overall.

Do these votes/edits count even if the question was closed afterwards? And do only the votes/edits count which I make or which also those I get?

Comment: Count towards what? Also, if I see this right you do not have sufficient privileges on any site to vote to close, you can only flag stuff.

Comment: @Bobby - Please check the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they count. Users simply can't add something to the discussion.
The only things that doesn't count is the deleted posts (questions and answers).